# Exception: unable to retrieve events for this subscription

Tags: .net, exchange-server

I have created a console application for listening the outbox mail box using exchange server.whenever  i send a mail to a particular outlook account my application read that mail and do some business functionality.Every functionality of this application is working fine. But i have  face one problem that when application has running a long time,like one day or more i try to send a mail. At that time the application can't process that listening event.An exception occurs.
**Unable to retrieve events for this subscription.  The subscription must be recreated**

How can I handle this situation? I think this problem is not only in the case of exchange server but also the common issue when an application keep running a long time.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, did you find the reason of the error?

Comment: @tommy what I did was i have hosted my application as scheduler and restart in a day or something. I couldn't find any other solution